# how do I solve Recursion tree problem on the equation

Tags: recursion, tree

How do I draw a recursion tree for T(n) = 4T(n-1) + 2. with n>1 and T(1) = 2. usually there is n in the end, but in this case there is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given recurrence relation has a constant term, which leads to a very trivial recursion tree:

```
      _______________2______________
     /          /        \          \
  __2__      __2__      __2__      __2__    
 / | | \    / | | \    / | | \    / | | \
2  2 2  2  2  2 2  2  2  2 2  2  2  2 2  2
...        ...        ...        ...
```

The number of levels of the tree is dermined by the recurrence term:  breaks down into <sub>−1</sub>, into <sub>−2</sub>, ... until <sub>1</sub>, so the tree has  levels.

First sum each level separately.

If we number the levels from the top to the bottom, with the top level numbered 0, and the bottom level −1, then level  has 4 nodes.

The number of all nodes is thus ∑<sub><sub>=0..−1</sub></sub>4. This represents the first terms of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula), and so we count (4−1)/3 nodes in the whole tree.

As each node has a value of 2, the total value is 2(4−1)/3